# Как передать значение через jQuery в php скрипт?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Не получается передать значение через jQuery в PHP. Пытаюсь передать значение `data-id` из `input` но ничего не передается. Что я делаю не так? Спасибо.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.who').bind("change keyup input click", function() {
        var reg_and_table = $(this).attr("data-id"); // Пытаюсь передать в search.php эту переменную
        console.log(reg_and_table);
        if(this.value.length >= 3){         
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "search.php",
                data: {'referal':this.value, reg_and_table: reg_and_table},
                response: 'text',
                success: function(data){
                    $(".search_result").html(data).fadeIn(); 
                }
            })
        } else if(this.value.length < 3){
                    $(".search_result").fadeOut();
        }
    })  

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="poisk" data-id="table1" type="text" name="referal" placeholder="Поиск" value="" class="who"  autocomplete="off">
```

Пытаюсь передать в search.php переменную reg_and_table

Comment: Путь к `search.php` укажите абсолютный

Comment: К сожалению, не помогает

Comment: Как вы проверяете, что на стороне сервера данные не приходят? Переменная `referal` так же не долетает?

Comment: referal  долетает. Проверяю через isset

Comment: Проверьте правильность написания ключа `reg_and_table`, сделайте вывод всего POST-массива

Comment: @ЮрийБерека воспроизвел Ваш код - все успешно передается в файл search.php Array
(
    [referal] => 1242
    [reg_and_table] => table1
)
Возможно Вы действительно не верный путь к файлу просто не указали, какой ответ?